# Homology group of a complement

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $A$ be a closed subset of $R^{n}$ homeomorphic to $R^{k}$, where $n \geq k$, what is homology group $H_{n}(R^{n}\backslash A)$? One more similar question: If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a sphere $S^{n}$, what is $H_{n}(S^{n}\backslash (A\cup B))$ such that $A\cap B=\{\text{single point}\}$? Kindly give full explanation.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$ is a non-compact $n$-dimensional manifold, so $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus A) = 0$.